# Ubuntu Sound Problem

Tags: sound, 15.04

I can only have one sound software working at a time, let´s say:

I got VLC open playing music and I proceed to watch a video on youtube.
The video will play with no sound until I pause VLC and back the youtube video page and return (refreshing page doesnt work).
The same will happen in VLC, if I have a youtube page with sound.

I am on Ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 0):

- check that VLC use Pulseaudio :
  in Vlc preferences , "Audio" tab, select "Pulseaudio" as output module .
  ("vlc-plugin-pulse" must be installed.)
- Pulseaudio must be ok and running: if you can set volume with standard sound setting, it is ok  .

Comment: Didn't solve :\